# how I can't declare Window object in javascript as a constructor like any object

Tags: javascript

I'am little bit curious why I can't declare Window object like that
`var win = new Window();`
it always give me an error saying  *Illegal constructor* what the problem here

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: The global [`Window` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is not a valid constructor, it's a holding-cell for other constructors, functions, etc. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AndrewLi just trying to declare it like any normal object

Comment: @hossahm To do what? jmargolisvt gave you good link if you're trying to open a new window on the user's browser, but other than I don't know why you'd want to instantiate `Window`...

Comment: @AndrewLi  ok thanks after a few search I discovered that Window object is an interface that is created once you opened the window that contains the DOM